# Side by side assemblies in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, assembly-loading

I am developing app where project has nuget dependency on PROJECTB of version 1.0.
However in development scenario I want to use this PROJECTB as submodule. In add that project to solution and change version to 2.0

However only PROJECTB of version 1.0 is in bin folder. I tried manually adding PROJECTB of version 2.0 to my project references of my main project but I get error:

An assembly with the same simple name PROJECT2 has already been imported

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing Dependencies from your Project first and then try again to import PROJECT2  with latest version.

Comment: Idea is that newest version is used only as git submodule while developing so it is easier and quicker then wait new version to be built using CI/CD for each line of code changed in projectb

Comment: Then you should add Project Reference instead of Assembly Reference

Comment: I added it as project reference

Comment: Can you please add more details on that, Also please double check .CSPROJ and .SLN file in for references